# Como fazer para que um arquivo em shell crie uma pagina em php

Tags: php, shell

Gostaria de fazer uma **MIB** (Management Information Base), que está criada, e tenho que criar o gerente e o agente. Estou usando `shell` para fazer isso, no agente tenho que criar uma pagina em `PHP`, para mostrar as informações da **MIB**, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Uso o interpretador `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

algo como

```
#!/bin/bash

cat << EOF > /var/www/html/teste.php
<?php
  echo "Funcionou?";
?>
EOF
```

deveria funcionar.

Comment: minha maior duvida é a seguinte, a pagina em PHP eu devo fazer fora do bash ou nele?

Comment: depende do que você quer fazer. No momento eu não consigo imaginar um caso onde realmente seja necessário usar o bash para gerar um php. Eu tentaria usar `shell_exec` no php antes de usar o bash.

Comment: tu tens algum exemplo que eu possa usar, é que meu professor veio com essa de MIB e não encontro nada na net, ele quer um gerente que faça a parte do php dai vai receber as informações da MIB, que estão em gerente

Comment: e outra coisa, eu sou muito fraco em shell :(